# Unity mobile: when the virtual keyboard is open, the first tap is not recognized

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I'm developing a simple unity mobile game for android devices where the user needs his virtual keyboard as a gameplay mechanic. This works great though I also want to have a "restart" button at the top right corner, so that the user can restart his game if he messes up.

My issue is: when the virtual keyboard is active/open and the users taps on the button, this tap is not recognized by unity (the keyboard slides down). Only the second tap on the button is recognized. Anybody stumbled upon this issue before?