# Input Field won't stay in focus while attempting to press button

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

- I created my first mobile application.
- This application has an input field and a button "add".
- When pressing on the add button, the input field stores the text in a variable and the input field is cleared.

Here's what's going on, when I try pressing on the button while my keyboard is up on my phone, the keyboard has to go down for the button press to work. But for what I need, the button should be functional despite the keyboard being up (**I don't want to click twice where the button is for it to work**)(as it stands, **the input field has to be out of focus to be able to click on said button**).

I'm very new to mobile devices and looked briefly online, but found no answers.

Is there any setting of sorts that would allow the button to be pressed while the keyboard is up? What am I doing wrong?

I know it's possible since other applications have that functionality.

Edit:

The button calls AddNewName() when pressed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewUser : MonoBehaviour {

    private InputField InputField;
    public Text Name;
    public void AddNewName()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name.text))
        {
            AppManager.Instance.UserList.Add(Name.text);
            InputField.text = string.Empty;
        }
        InputField.ActivateInputField();
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        InputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
        InputField.ActivateInputField();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            AddNewName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried focusing on the textbox again in the button's on click event?

Comment: That's what I'm doing but to press on the button, the input field has to be out of focus beforehand and then press the button.

Comment: It doesn't work but where is your code? Post the button event code and the InputField code and people here will likely point out your problem

Comment: I highly feel that the issue is not in my script and more of a setting in unity. I am using both the unity button script and the unity input field script. Apart from that, I will add the little code snip which I reset focus after the button is pressed but I don't feel that it has any importance.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre made a suggestion and you claimed that's what you did. Why not post the code? His suggestion is actually the solution. I see your edit. Please put a comment on the function that the button is calling

Comment: @Programmer "I will add the little code snip which I reset focus after the button is pressed but I don't feel that it has any importance."

Comment: Your current code is enough. AddNewName is being called by the Button? Last question, what is your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer Version 4.7.1f1

Comment: The issue isn't about the focus but more about having to press once anywhere other than the keyboard on the screen for the keyboard to disappear and then, and only then can the user press the add button.

Comment: I found [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778846/unity-mobile-when-the-virtual-keyboard-is-open-the-first-tap-is-not-recognized) that has the same question as mine but unfortunately has no answer...

Comment: I am about to try this on My Android to see what's going on

Comment: What is calling the `AddNewName` function? The `OnValueChanged` or `OnEndEdit` event?. Never mind. Saw this in your edit. This is a bug. I will see if  I can make a fix

Comment: [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-keyboard-issues.147669/) they say that this is a bug in unity and has yet to be fixed, but I didn't read too much into it and switched my concentration to other things... If it is a bug in unity, I hope it gets fixed in a later update.

I updated my unity to the latest and the bug has persisted.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just verified this. This is a serious bug. I tried to get some work around but it's not possible because on Android, when the keyboard is showing, the `Input` class stops working. I think that the keyboard is capturing all the Input events. My idea **was** to detect when user clicks outside the keyword then get use `Input` class to get the finger point of the user. After that, I can throw a fake `raycast` to see if it hit a button. This first part of this work around is not possible. Your only solution is to build your own keyboard plugin. This is possible but hard.

Comment: Alright, well thanks! I probably won't code a work around though since it's only a small project for fun. Is there any way to close an issue without having a solution since it's a bug? I wouldn't want to delete it in case anyone else hits into this issue and would like more information.

If ever a solution/fix to the bug is found though, the answer would then be accepted.